# Converse of Lagrange Theorem for p-groups.

Tags: group-theory

I need clarification on my understanding of Sylow Theorems.

Can I say that a finite p-group will have a subgroup for each prime power?
If the above is valid, can I say then that p-groups satisfy the converse of Lagrange Theorem?

I'm not sure of that statement. Can someone show me a counterexample of it if not? Thanks

Comment: Yes the converse of Lagrange's theorem holds for finite  $p$-groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of Alnitak refers to the class of finite groups known as *CLT groups*, where CLT stands for *Converse Lagrange Theorem*:

$G$ is a *CLT group* if for each positive integer $d$ dividing $|G|$, $G$ has at least one subgroup of order $d$.

These groups have been studied extensively. It turns out for example that all [supersolvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersolvable_group) groups are CLT, and all CLT groups are [solvable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). See also one of the early [papers](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102983900) of Henry G. Bray, Pac. J. Math 27 (1968). All $p$-groups, or in general nilpotent groups, are supersolvable.